# How can I use external h2 tags to make LiquidSlider 2 change content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am developing a website and I have been using [LiquidSlider2](http://liquidslider.com/)
to place content in. I have h2 tags below the div the contains the slider. I want to place those H2 tags in an anchor tag to make those H2s change the content. Can I do this?

```
            <div class="liquid-slider" id="main-slider">
            <div>
                <h2 class="title">Slide 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2 class="title">Slide 2</h2>
                <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2 class="title">Slide 3</h2>
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2 class="title">Slide 4</h2>
                <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The slider. Pretty straight forward.

```
<div class="row" id="bottomBanners">
    <div id="bottomBanner1" class="large-3 columns small-6 columns">
        <p class="bannerText"><a class="#1">DIDs</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomBanner2" class="large-3 columns small-6 columns">
        <p class="bannerText"><a class="#2">Orig</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomBanner3" class="large-3 columns small-6 columns">
        <p class="bannerText">Term</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomBanner4" class="large-3 columns small-6 columns">
        <p class="bannerText">E911</p>
    </div>

</div><!--End row-->
```

The banners that i want to change the content. I tried following his example with the tabs and giving the a class of #1 and #2 but that didnt work.

Comment: You should re read http://liquidslider.com/documentation/#externalcontrols-options there is a documentation for **crossLinks** like this: `<a href="#slide-3" data-liquidslider-ref="slider-id">Slide 3</a>`. Add a link to your headlines

Comment: If I would have read the page a little more carefully I would have seen that. Thank you for pointing it out for me.

Comment: you're welcome. good luck with the project.

Comment: I have a question. I'm unclear on the documentation. Do I have to change crossLinks: false to true. Because I searched through the files and couldn't find that. Or do I just have to add that link to my anchor tag?

Comment: I havent used this plugin before. The Docs say: "If you want to control the slider from anywhere on the page, you must enable cross links." So i guess yes. you will have to activate it before.